# Hot to ground voltage reads ~1 volt but breaker is not tripped

Tags: lighting, switch, circuit-breaker, grounding, circuit

Summary: I'm seeing a very low voltage read in between the hot wire and the ground in a switch. Yet the circuit breaker isn't tripped and everything works fine. Should I do something about it? If so, what?

Longer version:

OK, so I wanted to upgrade a switch in my house, seems easy enough. The box looks like the image below. There's two simple switches, controlling two independent lights (on the same circuit). There's 4 wires coming into/out of the box. My assumption is that two of them are the loads (lights), one of them comes from the panel, and one of them continues on to feed other loads in the circuit. I believe there are 6 total loads in the circuit: 5 lights and 1 outlet.
[image: switch box]

I took a multimeter to confirm which wire was hot. I expected a read of ~120V between the hot and ground, but I get a read of ~1V (it kinda fluctuates a bit), which is very surprising. Here are all the readings:

- hot to ground on either switch: 1V
- load to ground on either switch: 0
- hot to load on right switch: 93V
- hot to load on left switch: 120V

These readings are with the switches turned off, and with everything else (that I know of) in the circuit turned off: lights off, nothing plugged into outlet.

Now, my understanding is extremely basic, but doesn't that mean that somewhere in the circuit, there's probably a connection between the hot and ground (maybe with a small resistance, because the read is not 0)? But if so, wouldn't that cause the circuit breaker to trip?

What could be going on here? Maybe the circuit doesn't trip because the ground cable is broken somewhere along the line? Or it doesn't because the breaker is not a GFCI one, just a regular one? Should I do anything about this, or just blindly replace the switch and move on? Also, why does one switch read 93V instead of 120V?

Thanks!

Comment: ~1v is probably phantom.  Very good chance your ground wire is not complete to the panel, which means it is useless for your safety, that is the only reason for a ground wire to protect you, not to make the circuit work.  Would check other circuits/boxes and see if the ground works/is connected to the panel.

Comment: This smells like a bad/broken ground wire, indeed.

Comment: Breakers should only trip if the circuit pulls too many amps, usually a short, but if ground is not connected to the panel and a hot wire touches it, nothing happens, till you touch the broken ground and a good ground.  Fun fun fun for people watching, you not so much.

Comment: Carefully unbundle the neutrals and check from the neutral bunch (if you keep them connected together but uncapped then you don't have to figure out which is from panel) to ground and from the neutral bunch to the various hot and load wires. Should show 0V between neutral and grounds and ~120V to the hots.